# Що таке "косити віку"? І що таке "віка"?

Tags: значення-слів, фразеологізми

Василь Вражливий, "Дівчина":

> І кожного вечора, кожної ночі співали посмішки. Тільки з зорею
>   стомлені заснули...
>
> А вранці Гордій ішов **косити віку** і все згадував Марину.
>
> — Клята дівчина! Чого морочить? Вдруге відразу засну.

Шукаю в ґуґлі, в словниках, в [корпусі](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac&reload=&iquery=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%83&queryselector=iqueryrow&lemma=&phrase=&word=&char=&cql=&default_attr=word&fc_lemword_window_type=both&fc_lemword_wsize=5&fc_lemword=&fc_lemword_type=all&usesubcorp=&fsca_doc.author=&fsca_doc.title=&fsca_doc.date=&fsca_doc.region=&fsca_doc.translator=&fsca_doc.born=&fsca_doc.publisher=&fsca_doc.publication=&fsca_doc.uri=) ГРАК, але знаходжу лише два схожих приклади використання, а пояснення самого вислову не знаходжу. Допоможіть, будь ласка.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Правильна назва рослини **вика**, проте в народі часто називають ***віка***, за аналогією до скороченої форми жіночого імені Вікторія.

[УСЕ (Універсальний словник-енциклопедія):](http://slovopedia.org.ua/29/53394/7728.html)

> ВИКА  одно- або багаторічна трав'яниста рослина родини бобових; бл.
>   120 видів, поширені здебільшого в пн. півкулі; вирощують переважно в.
>   яру і в. озиму на зелений корм, сіно, силос. I

[Орфографічний словник української мови:](http://slovopedia.org.ua/35/53394/50811.html)

> ви́ка  іменник жіночого роду  кормова бобова рослина

[Українсько-російський словник:](http://slovopedia.org.ua/47/53394/306208.html)

> бот.  вика

[Великий тлумачний словник (ВТС) сучасної української мови:](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53394/838919.html)

> вика 
>   -и, ж. Кормова бобова рослина, плоди якої мають форму довгих стручків.

[СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=8960&page=318)

> ВИ́КА, и, жін. Кормова бобова рослина, плоди якої мають форму довгих
>   стручків.

Answer (score 7):

Гордій косив вику - рослину, яка вирощується як зелене добриво і на корм худобі ([Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0)). Народна назва - віка посівна (сайт [Аграрії разом](https://agrarii-razom.com.ua/plants/vika)). До речі, ви в питанні дали посилання, де є приклад який підтверджує цю теорію:

> Раптом Федот згадав , що такий самий мотивчик наспівував батько , коли
>   косив віку на корм худобі